# Frontend: Internet Explorer problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, explorer

How is it possible to check in javascript that the user has opened the application in internet Explorer? For that case, I would like to replace some elements that are not supported in IE.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect IE version with Javascript.

```js
// Get IE or Edge browser version
var version = detectIE();

if (version === false) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<s>IE/Edge</s>';
} else if (version >= 12) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Edge ' + version;
} else {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'IE ' + version;
}

// add details to debug result
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = window.navigator.userAgent;

/**
 * detect IE
 * returns version of IE or false, if browser is not Internet Explorer
 */
function detectIE() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

  // Test values; Uncomment to check result …

  // IE 10
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)';
  
  // IE 11
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';
  
  // Edge 12 (Spartan)
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0';
  
  // Edge 13
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586';

  var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
  if (msie > 0) {
    // IE 10 or older => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
  }

  var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
  if (trident > 0) {
    // IE 11 => return version number
    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
    return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
  }

  var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
  if (edge > 0) {
    // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
  }

  // other browser
  return false;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Mono|Fira+Sans:300);

body {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
}

h1 {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

p {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Fira Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Detect IE/Edge version with JavaScript.<br>
  Updated to recognize Internet Explorer 12+ aka Edge.</h1>
<h2 id="result">detecting…</h2>
<p id="details">n/a</p>
```

I hope this helps you.